# App Store subscription with free trial allowed?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, subscription

My app let the user input very specific types of data, and offer online synchronization. To use the app, you must pay a subscription (auto renewing subscription in-app purchase).

However, I would like to include a free trial. I cannot use the free trial option of in-app purchase products because this is only allowed for newsstand apps (according to WWDC 2012 session videos, session 308 "Managing Subscriptions with IAP")

Here is my idea of workaround to achieve similar functionality :

1. The user creates an account on my app
2. This account is given a short free subscription for testing the app. Subscription is managed server-side. During the trial, there is no restrictions on the app
3. When the trial is over, the user will not be able to insert new data, or sync with the server. He will be prompted to subscribe to continue using the app

I have a doubt if this is acceptable for the App Store. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Question is meaningful and relevant, why did you close it? I know at least one app that has time-limited trial (before IAP), "myTifi" remote for Samsung TVs, http://appshopper.com/utilities/tifi-remote . Pls vote to re-open!

Comment: I got to talk with an Apple Review Team representative, and this person explained to me that an app cannot go "dead" after a period of time : i.e. there need some kind of functionality remaining, otherwise the app would be rejected. So I believe this is allowed, however our app was rejected for other unclear reasons, so I could not verify this idea

Answer (score 1):

Technically that would work but two problems arise:
One: if you don't use in app purchasing then the users can't buy your service from the app (its in the dev agreement)
Two: if you do use in app purchasing then you trust the IOS devices to say "hey I just bought one year service so hook me up" one could hack this http://zd.net/LkY9Ra and make your server give service to illegitimate users. Will this happen? not likely but it can.
Kinda sucks apple forces developers to a clearly flawed model

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One: I do plan to use IAP to buy the service (autorenewable subscriptions). Two: The user has an account on our servers, and the app/server will check if he has a valid receipt before providing any functionality. The IAP hack cannot work if the server checks if the receipt is valid